# como imprimir una matriz bidimensional con recursividad en c#

Tags: c#

Necesito imprimir los datos de una matriz 3*3 por ejemplo pero de forma recursiva o sea sin usar ciclos

Comment: y que fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: es que solo la puedo imprimir con ciclos y la profe no lo quiere de esa forma lo quiere de forma recursiva

Comment: Ok, coloca el codigo que intentaste para sobre ese codigo ayudarte.

Comment: solo tengo el codigo con ciclo,pero no era de esa forma; no tengo un codigo con recursividad ,es por eso la pregunta

Comment: si te entendi, igual coloca ese codigo con ciclo

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace arreglo_clasea {
    class Program {

        static public void Imprimir(int[,]Matriz) {


            for (int filas=0; filas<3; filas++) 
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for(int columnas=0; columnas<4; columnas++) 
                {
                    Console.Write("\t"+ Matriz[filas,columnas]+"\t");
                }

Comment: Main() {
            int[,] Matriz = new int[3,4]; //3x4
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)//for externo para filas
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)//for interno para columnas
                    {
                    Console.Write("ingrese el valor de la posicion [" +i +","+j+"]:"); //[0,0]
                    Matriz[i,j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                   
                    }
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("ahora visualizamos la matriz");
            Imprimir(Matriz);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Answer (score -1):

La recursividad es la forma de llamar un metodo a si mismo hasta lograr una condicion y hacer que esta misma le de fin al ciclo recursivo.
Veras que en el `if` compruebo el tamaño de la matriz.
Cuando la columna llega a su fin, le incremento el valor a la fila y reseteo el valor de la columna.

```
class Program
{
    static int[,] Matriz = new int[3, 3];

    static int F1 = 0;
    static int C1 = 0;
    static int total = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                Matriz[f, c] = random.Next();
            }
        }
        RecursividadFilas();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    private static void RecursividadFilas()
    {
        if (F1 < Matriz.Length / 3)
        {
            if (C1 < Matriz.Length / 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fila: {F1}, Column: {C1} - Valor: {Matriz[F1, C1]}");
                C1++;
                total++;
                if (C1 == 3)
                {
                    F1++;
                    C1 = 0;
                }
            }
            RecursividadFilas();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: con varialbes globales?, y si deseo ejecutar nuevamente ?, mil disculpas pero lo que hiciste no parece ser muy optimo.-1

Comment: El ejemplo es para que entienda la recursividad en este caso, no entiendo porque verificas la optimizacion y no que funcione el problema que plantea. y si uso variables locales en el metodo se reiniciarian cada vez que se llama el metodo asi mismo y no funcionaria correctamente. Si lo queres llamar nuevamente, desde donde lo quieras hacer, invocas el metodo y lo adaptas a tu necesidad. No entiendo tu duda.

Comment: me prohibieron usar funciones como: length, pero de igual forma muchas gracias!!, trataré de hacerlo

Comment: simplemente le pones el valor fijo del tamaño y listo.

Comment: @lizett si te sirvio, marcala como correcta.